# History and bookmark feature in Android application

Tags: android, database, history, bookmarks

In my app, I want to add history and add to favorites features. It's an offline app of book details, hence I need to see which book detail was recently viewed and save it to database. How to do that?

Comment: Hey did u get any idea of creating such a app?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all have a rough estimate of the number of records you want ( history depth, favorites depth ).
2. How do you plan to reference a detail. Will a detail consist of multiple pages and do you want the addressability ( if there is such a word ) to the page level - OR - do you want to maintain a history of details.
3. If all you are saving is a DetailID etc, you may even just use [SharedPreferences](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html), rather than using the [database](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742).
4. You could use the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) events like onCreate, onResume, onPause etc to track loading / unloading of details.

Comment: is there any example to see..i am new to java and android, it will be great help.

Comment: Could you please be more specific as the example of what you are looking for ? Did you get a chance to play with the examples cited in my post ?